# Gunicorn can't connect

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I try to run django with nginx and gunicorn. I'm following the tutorial http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/ but my structure is a bit difference.

**/home/vagrant/src**

```
.
├── manage.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

My virtualenv is /home/vagrant/venv. When i run:

```
/home/vagrant/venv/bin/gunicorn_start
```

I get error:

```
sudo -u src ./gunicorn_start 
Starting src as src
[2015-02-07 17:13:26 +0000] [11793] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x1275758>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x1275488>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x12755f0>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 998
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 3
  proc_name: src
  sendfile: True
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x1275320>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x1275cf8>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x12758c0>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x1279410>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x1275e60>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x1275f50>
  user: 998
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x1275a28>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x1279140>
  chdir: /home/vagrant/src/src
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: src.wsgi:application
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x12751b8>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x1275b90>
  bind: ['unix:/home/vagrant/venv/run/gunicorn.sock']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x12792a8>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix: 
[2015-02-07 17:08:25 +0000] [11764] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-07 17:08:25 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-02-07 17:08:26 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-02-07 17:08:27 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-02-07 17:08:28 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-02-07 17:08:29 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-02-07 17:08:30 +0000] [11764] [ERROR] Can't connect to /home/vagrant/venv/run/gunicorn.sock
```

gunicorn.sock exists